# How to insert list of new column names to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame from an existing excel file. I have extracted the columns of the dataframe and have done `strip`() and `lower`() operations. I am finding issue of inserting new list of columns into the dataframe.

Here is the below code :

```
import pandas as pd

import itertools

def fetch_columns(req_columns, input_columns):

    keys = req_columns.keys()

    def func1(key):
        return req_columns[key]

    def func2(col):
        if col in input_columns:
            return col

    alias_col = list(map(func1, keys))
    flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*alias_col))
    col_names = list(filter(func2, flat_list))

    rename_col = dict(zip(col_names, keys))
    return {'actual_columns': col_names, 'rename_columns': rename_col}


def read_file(file_name):

    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    print(df)
    input_columns = list(df.columns.str.strip().str.lower())
    print(input_columns)
    df = df[input_columns]
    print(df)
    req_columns = {'emp_id': ['uid', 'empid'], 'emp_name': ['name', 'empname']}
    result = fetch_columns(req_columns, input_columns)
    columns = list(result.values())

    df = df[columns[0]]
    print(df)
    df.rename(columns=columns[1], inplace=True)
    return df


df = read_file('col_read.xlsx')

print(df.head())
```

data of 'col_read.xlsx':

UID  NAME  empage   age

1     skd    23      23

I have extracted UID, NAME, empage, age from the excel file and created a pandas dataframe and have applied strip() and lower() methods on it. The newlist of lowercased and empty space stripped column names is what I want to replace with the old dataframe column names.And that is where I am finding error.

KeyError: "['uid', 'name'] not in index"

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to change the name of the df columns and have a list of said names, you can: `df.columns = new_col_names`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Select only certain columns from the dataframe and rename them?

Comment: Solution given by Kosmos worked. Thank you Kosmos